# Flint Hills series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3\sin^2 n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

The well known [Flint Hills series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FlintHillsSeries.html),

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3\sin^2 n}$$Since I'm aware   of the fact that the series convergence issue is still unknown or falls under  unsolved problem however, making  check on [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%3D1+n%3D+infinite++cosec%5E2n%2F%28n%5E3%29),  the infinite sum has been approximated $\sim 4.80$.

Similarly, I came [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/355300697927549/permalink/1947628882028048/?app=fbl) where the proposer, *Tobi Ope* claims that

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3\sin^2 n} =3\zeta(5)-\frac{2}{\pi^2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cot k}{k^4}\tag{1}$$ which doesn't meet the approximation done by Wolfram alpha.

Whether the series converges or not which is still a big unsolved issue so I believe the equality $(1)$ done is incorrect?

Similarly, what is wrong with Wolfram alpha? Is it possible to approximate or find the possible closed form for any such infinite series whose convergence is unknown?

Thank you

Comment: Actually if it isn't convergent the sum is sufficient by itself. But it is actually a very interesting problem to wonder if it converges or not.

Comment: @EDX, If the sum isn't sufficient, it should imply the convergence?   How can it be possible if problem isnot convergent?

Comment: I mean that finding a closed form if it isn't convergent is not meaningful. That means the expression of the sum is largely sufficient.

Comment: Aww,  I get it now, so does I think. Thank you:)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: (1) has an infinite series on each side. I would say that (1) is true if both series diverge, in the sense that any two divergent series are equal; false, if one series converges and the other diverges; if both series converge, then it's true if it's true. Perhaps Tobi Ope, or someone, has a proof that the series on the left converges if and only if the series on the right converges. That would be interesting.

Comment: You need only one n very close to a multiple of pi, within 1 / (2.2 n^ 1.5), and the infinite sum is larger then 4.8.

Comment: Ratio test in [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yvuuxdc5nx) does not converge, so likely Flint Hill’s series does not either. Right?

Answer (score 1):

This is changed now, it says the series diverges. Now, that is just a limitation of Wolfram Alpha, indeed, in Wolfram Mathematica 13.2.1 (Alpha is still 12 version, indeed, see [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5Bx%2FSqrt%5Bx%5E4+%2B+10+x%5E2+-+96+x+-+71%5D%2C+x%5D](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5Bx%2FSqrt%5Bx%5E4%20%2B%2010%20x%5E2%20-%2096%20x%20-%2071%5D%2C%20x%5D)) it just returns SumConvergence[Csc[n]^2/n^3, n], because that cannot be solved. In fact it cannot even solve the series that depend on Pi measure **that we know Pi has already**, last example here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/258979/82985 proved by genius Terence Tao here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/282290/160207